# How to retrieve specific chars after decimal using REGEX in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm using RegEx in a View in Oracle 11g and I need to display certain codes that have an 'S' in the 8th position.

Using https://regexr.com/2v41h,

I was able to display these results with 
`REGEXP_SUBSTR(code, '\S{8}')`

`Y38.9X2S
Y38.9X2D
Y38.9X2A
Y38.9X1S`

My issue is that I need to return only the values that have an 'S' in the last position which is the 8th position counting the decimal.  What expression should I use?

Example:

`Y38.9X2S
Y38.9X1S`

I have tried:
`REGEXP_SUBSTR(code, '\b[S]*[8]\b') AS CODE`

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Just use `'\S{7}S'`

Comment: Thank you very much.  That worked perfectly.  I was overthinking with brackets and multiple expressions with the decimal.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: No worries. If you're happy with the results `\S{8}` was giving you (other than the traling `S`) that should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking:

```
select substr(code, -8)
from t
where code like '%_______S'
```

If the code is always long enough, just use `'%S'`.

Or, as a `case` expression:

```
select (case when code like '%_______S' then substr(code, -8) end)
```

You will need regular expressions if `code` has other characters but they may not be necessary.